# Imprimir matrices una al lado de otra en JAVA

Tags: java, matrices

Me gustaria saber si me pueden ayudar a imprimir una matriz una al lado de otra en java, yo tengo este codigo actualmente que es el que practicamente imprime las matrices pero una sobre la otra. Necesito una al lado de la otra :)

Gracias

```
System.out.println("Iniciando juego...");
System.out.println();
System.out.println("          Matriz A");
System.out.println();

for (int x=0; x < d.Matriz_A.length; x++) {
    System.out.print("|");

    for (int y=0; y < d.Matriz_A[x].length; y++) {
        System.out.print(d.Matriz_A[x][y]);

        if (y!=d.Matriz_A[x].length-1)    
            System.out.print("\t");
    }

    System.out.println("|");
}

System.out.println("");     
System.out.println("");

System.out.println();       
System.out.println("         Matriz H");
System.out.println();

for (int x=0; x < d.Matriz_B.length; x++) {
    System.out.print("|");
    for (int y=0; y < d.Matriz_B[x].length; y++) {
        System.out.print ("~");

        if (y!=d.Matriz_B[x].length-1)
            System.out.print("\t");
    }
    System.out.println("|");
}
```

Comment: usa `print` en vez de `println`

Comment: Se desordena terriblemente! No tienes de casualidad un ejemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es pintar los elementos de la fila x de la matriz A y luego los elementos de la fila x de la matriz B. Para lograr esto, entre otras cosas, debes utilizar `System.out.print()` para pintar cada elemento en vez de `System.out.println()`. Solo cuando termines de pintar el último elemento de la fila x de la matriz B debes utilizar `System.out.println()` para agregar una salto de línea y así la próxima fila la pintas en una nueva línea.

El código quedaría así.

```
int colCountMatrizA = Matriz_A[0].length;

for (int x1 = 0, x2 = 0; x1 < Matriz_A.length || x2 < Matriz_B.length; x1++, x2++) {

    // Si no se han pintado todas las filas de la matriz A
    if (x1 < Matriz_A.length) {
        System.out.print("|");

        for (int y1 = 0; y1 < Matriz_A[x1].length; y1++) {
            System.out.print(Matriz_A[x1][y1]);

            if (y1 != Matriz_A[x1].length - 1) {
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
        }

        System.out.print("|");
    } else {
        // Si ya se pintaron todas las filas e la matriz A
        // Esto lo hago para que la matriz B siempre quede alineada en caso de la matriz A tenga menos filas
        for (int i = 0; i < colCountMatrizA - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
    }

    // Si no se han pintado todas las filas de la matriz A
    if (x2 < Matriz_B.length) {
        System.out.print("\t\t|");

        for (int y2 = 0; y2 < Matriz_B[x2].length; y2++) {
            System.out.print(Matriz_B[x2][y2]);

            if (y2 != Matriz_B[x2].length - 1) {
                System.out.print("\t");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("|");
    }
}
```

### **Pruebas**

**Prueba 1**
Entrada:

```
int[][] Matriz_A = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};<br/>
int[][] Matriz_B = {{7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 13, 13, 14}, {15, 16, 17, 18}};
```

Salida:

```
C:\Users\Test\Desktop>java Test
|1      2       3|              |7      8       9       10|
|4      5       6|              |11     13      13      14|
                                |15     16      17      18|
```

**Prueba 2**
Entrada:

```
int[][] Matriz_A = {{7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 13, 13, 14}, {15, 16, 17, 18}};
int[][] Matriz_B = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};<br/>
```

Salida:

```
C:\Users\Test\Desktop>java Test
|7      8       9       10|             |1      2       3|
|11     13      13      14|             |4      5       6|
|15     16      17      18|
```

Comment: Funciono perfectamente!! Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Un placer ayudarte. Saludos!